# Syntax Error on Apache 2.2.25 update

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server

just upgraded to Apache2.2.25 from 2.2. I can call the version (httpd -v) but when I do apachectl start, I get the following error.

httpd: Syntax error on line 63 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so, 10): Symbol not found: _apr_stat$INODE64\n Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so\n Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authz_owner.so

If I comment out the line in the httpd.conf file it then gives me an error on another line and on and on.

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade ?  It looks to me like you either need to build/install the modules for the new version of Apache.

Comment: I looked in the Apache2 folder in /usr/local/ and found a /modules directory with all the modules in it. so it seems like they are there  How would I go about building/installing the version again?

Comment: I tried to edit my comment but ran out of time.  I downloaded the source files from Apache, expanded them on my desktop and tried to run the */configure - make - make install command.  It wouldn't compile, so I found a workaround on Apple Forum that disabled some of the mods and it worked.  2.2.25 compiled and installed and gave me back the version when I did httpd -v.  But it would not start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility of the same error like:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_XYZ.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_XYZ.so, 10): image not found
```

This could happen if you have created a symbolic link that is being referred in the name above and it is not found. To resolve create a symbolic link providing the absolute path for the actual file and also for the symlink file name being provided.